# C# TeamCity: Multiple SDK Version Problem

Tags: c#, .net-core, teamcity

Trying to get my project to build via our internal TeamCity server, and I'm hitting on a problem with SDK versions. The first step is a `dotnet restore` command on my project, and it fails with the following error:

```
[12:51:55]  Updating sources: auto checkout (on agent) (42s)
[12:52:38]  Step 1/5: Restore (.NET CLI (dotnet)) (5s)
[12:52:39]  [Step 1/5] dotnet.exe restore MySolution.sln @D:\teamcity\buildagent2\temp\agentTmp\a057a13bb8fb4a43a4b14c8cebf2d41a.rsp
[12:52:39]  [Step 1/5] restore (4s)
[12:52:39]  [restore] Starting: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore MySolution.sln @D:\teamcity\buildagent2\temp\agentTmp\a057a13bb8fb4a43a4b14c8cebf2d41a.rsp
[12:52:39]  [restore] in directory: D:\teamcity\buildagent2\work\48acce6beee4a7d3
[12:52:43]  [restore] c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1.
[12:52:43]  [restore] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\NuGet.targets(103,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore!
[12:52:43]  [restore] 
[12:52:43]  [restore] Build succeeded.
[12:52:43]  [restore] 
[12:52:43]  [restore] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\NuGet.targets(103,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore!
[12:52:43]  [restore]     1 Warning(s)
[12:52:43]  [restore]     1 Error(s)
[12:52:43]  [restore] 
[12:52:43]  [restore] Time Elapsed 00:00:01.84
[12:52:43]  [restore] 
[12:52:43]  [restore] 
[12:52:44]  [restore] c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1.
[12:52:43]  [restore] Process exited with code 0
[12:52:43]  [Step 1/5] Step Restore (.NET CLI (dotnet)) failed
[12:52:44]  Publishing internal artifacts
[12:52:44]  Build finished
```

As far as I can tell, it is calling two different SDK's, and my project targets .NET Core 2.1. I've tried specifying the Project target (single Project solution):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>MyProject.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I've also tried to specify the target SDK version via a `global.json` file as referenced [here](https://markheath.net/post/switching-between-netcore-sdk-versions):

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.200"
  }
}
```

All of these have been met with the same error as seen in the build log I provided. Can anyone provide a suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: I dont have an answer, but a couple of comments. .NET Core 2.0 is set to be End-of-Life on October 1, 2018. That's about 2 business days. No update (security, performance, bugfixes) will be provided for it after that. Targetting `netcoreapp2.1` is the right thing to do. .NET Core SDK "2.0.2" and "2.1.2" are both the .NET Core 2.0 SDK (the one that's EOL'ing). I dont know about TeamCity. Can you install a newer version of .NET Core SDK on it? Their github page has steps on how to tell it to user a newer CLI (aka SDK): https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-dotnet-plugin#net-cli-toolkit

Comment: Oh, one more comment: it's possible to install as my versions of the SDK side-by-side. In your case, "2.0.2" and "2.1.2" seem to be installed in one location. I would recommend adding a 2.1-capable sdk, such as 2.1.402, in there too. (And maybe then tell dotnet to use that sdk explicitly by using the global.json file, like you tried to use. The latest sdk is used by default).

Comment: Thanks @omajid, I went ahead and provided the answer with the details you provided, and added links to the .NET Core SDK downloads page that shows the versioning of SDK vs runtime. To answer your question, no, I can't update what's on the build server, but I'm going to be working with my build manager and IT team to make sure we get updated SDK's and runtimes throughout the environments.

Answer (score 0):

As @omajid stated in the comments, 2.0.2 and 2.1.2 versions of the SDK's are in fact both on the .NET Core 2.0 runtime. The first .NET Core 2.1 runtime SDK version was 2.1.300, as found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1). .NET Core 2.0 runtime includes both 2.0.2 and 2.1.2 SDK versions as seen [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.0).